# Is a Methoxy group meta directing in this problem?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds

The following question was given in **chemistry today , August 2020 edition** , page 47 , problem 9. The answer to this problem is (a).
[image]

**My Attempt**

[image]

In the third step , the carbon electrophile can attack at ortho position to carbon substituent to give a 6 membered ring.

But , the O-Methyl group is ortho para directing. The resonance structures are as follows.

[image]

The given answer is , a , is possible only if **we consider** O-Methyl group on Benzene as meta directing group.

**My Question:**

Is methoxy group on ANISOLE **Meta** directing ?

Comment: The presence of the OMe activates the whole ring to electrophilic attack. The o & p positions are most activated but m is also activated. Your attempted mechanism is correct

Comment: Anisole is a whole. The question in the last line is wrong in terms, Even if we know what you mean.

Comment: My question is how did the CH2 group para to the methoxy shift to a meta position? Unless this question represents a surprising mechanism, answer d seems to make the most sense.

Comment: I agree, d is the product

Comment: @Waylander , understood that Methoxy group activates ring. But electrophillic attack at meta gives an intermediate that is relatively unstable. Since intermediate is unstable , can EAS occur ?

Comment: It is possible for the electrophile to attack at the para position, followed by an alkyl shift to the meta position. The best answer would still be (d), I think, although it depends on which group migrates. (a) makes no sense, I'm afraid. There's no way anything can get *ortho* to the methoxy.

Comment: @ChakravarthyKalyan   Ortho attack is impossible as the electrophilic centre simply cannot reach the ortho position. Once that is ruled out you have to ask "what is next most favourable reaction pathway?"

Comment: Are you not concerned how an E-double bond becomes Z in the cyclized product?

Comment: The saturated acid is known to undergo FC cyclization to 7-methoxytetralone.

Comment: The double bond geometry is not specified in the original question.

Answer (score 3):

Now that the general consensus of the Commenters is that meta cyclization is viable and that the answer is (**d**) and not (**a**), the OP and other readers should be concerned as to how an (*E*)-double bond can cyclize in a Friedel-Crafts (F-C) reaction. It doesn't! Prior isomerization to the (*Z*)-configuration is required. 
(*E*)-Acyl chloride **1** must rotate about the red β-γ single bond and $\ce{AlCl3}$ must complex with the carbonyl oxygen forming species **2**. [*One may also invoke $\ce{AlCl3}$ complexation with the chlorine and rationalize the subsequent steps via an acylium ion and conjugated ketenes. The principle is the same.*] Loss of a proton at the γ-position of conformation **2** provides the β,γ-(*Z*)-double bond of **3**. Now deconjugated acyl chloride **4** is ready for F-C cyclization to intermediate **7** and onto 7-methoxynaphthalen-1-ol (**9**), aka (**d**). Alternatively, rotation about the red bond in **3** leads to conformation **5**, which, upon γ-protonation leads to α,β-(*Z*)-conjugated acyl chloride **6**. Subsequent F-C cyclization via intermediate **8** affords **9**. Incidently, base is not required to produce **9** from **7** or **8**. F-C conditions are sufficient.

[image]